# Paypal IPN on Sandbox mode

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

I had installed IPN on my account which seems to be working on IPN simulator, but when testing on Sandbox mode, it is not working.
This is my code, am I having something wrong?

```
<?php
  $req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';

  foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
    $req .= "&$key=$value";
  }

  //Set up the acknowledgement request headers
  $header .= "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.0\r\n";
  $header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
  $header .= "Host: www.sandbox.paypal.com\r\n";
  $header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n";

  //Open a socket for the acknowledgement request
  $fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.sandbox.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);

  // Post request back to PayPal for validation
  fputs ($fp, $header . $req);


   while (!feof($fp)) {                     // While not EOF
    $res = fgets ($fp, 1024);              // Get the acknowledgement response

    if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {  // Response is VERIFIED

      // Send an email announcing the IPN message is VERIFIED
      $mail_From = "IPN@example.com";
      $mail_To = "me@gmail.com";
      $mail_Subject = "VERIFIED IPN";
      $mail_Body = $req;
      mail($mail_To, $mail_Subject, $mail_Body, $mail_From);
    }
    else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) { // Response is INVALID

      // Notification protocol is NOT complete, begin error handling

      // Send an email announcing the IPN message is INVALID
      $mail_From = "IPN@example.com";
      $mail_To = "me@gmail.com";
      $mail_Subject = "INVALID IPN";
      $mail_Body = $req;
      mail($mail_To, $mail_Subject, $mail_Body, $mail_From);

    }
  }

  fclose ($fp);
?>
```

Is it something that I have wrong in the code or is it a problem from Paypal? How can I solve this problem?

On other hand, my account is verified with Paypal

Comment: Have you checked your account and looked at the IPN logs to make sure that the IPN's are being sent out from your account?  This will also show you if your site is returning back something other than a 200ok response.

Comment: After spending hours with some sample codes , even the one from paypal self , the above snippet succeed my tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it is a problem in Paypal documentation, and yesterday I discovered I needed to do these steps:

- Create two accounts in developer.paypal.com for the real account (Seller Account), and a buyer account in the Sandbox mode.
- Manage the seller account on sandbox.paypal.com to be Premier account and you need to double check that you enabled IPN on the sandbox seller account! (Which I was missing because I thought settings is the same as the real account on paypal.com)

The code is working perfectly, it was a matter of mysterious settings.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same trouble,

But the problem is from Paypal sandbox interface, there server didn't call my notification url.

It seems riht now,

Please Try again!

:)